# converting list variables within data frame to data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have read data from a sav (spss) file.  Using the following code:

```
library(foreign)
test <- read.spss(path_to_file, to.data.frame = TRUE)
```

the resultant data frame is in the following format:

```
structure(list(srl = c(4096, 15024, 4094), mem_id = c(278812, 
2341700, 251337), q1 = c(2, 2, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

While the object `test` is a `data frame`, each of the columns is rendered as a `list`. I tried the following to convert:

```
dd <- data.frame(srl = unlist(df$srl), mem_id = unlist(df$mem_id), q1 = unlist(df$q1))
```

still the resultant data frame is in the same as given in the dput.

Comment: Hrm... the `structure` you posted has `num` columns, not list no list-columns... so I can't replicate your problem... but just guessing randomly, how bout trying purrr::map(test,unlist)

Comment: A dataframe is a list of vectors. All vectors in the list have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Even if we cannot reproduce it and run it so that we could check if it works, why don't you try:

lst <- lst[-c(4,5)]

and then

new_lst <- as.data.frame(lst)

,where lst is the name of your list. I suggest remove the 4th and 5th element cause in a dataframe you probably won't need it.